# Converting Python Dictionary to List of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dict:

```
d={10:[2,"str1",4] , 20:[5,"str2",7] , 30:[8,"str3",10]}
```

I need to make a list from this dict:

```
lst=[[10,2,"str1",4] , [20,5,"str2",7] ,[30,8,"str3",10]]
```

if I use `lst`= map(list, d.items())` the key is not in the same list like the values:

```
lst=[[10,[2,"str1",4]] , [20,[5,"str2",7]] ,[30,[8,"str3",10]]
```

I also tried this code:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    for i in v:
        lst=[]
        lst.append([k,i])
```

I dont know why but I get only this:

```
lst=[[10,2]]
```

Comment: You're resetting `lst` to an empty list in each iteration of your inner loop.

Comment: `lst=[]` should be outside of loops...

Comment: try `[[k]+v for k,v in d.items()]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst=[]
lst.append([k,i])
```

is the same as

```
lst=[k,i]
```

Not very useful in a loop.

To avoid those initialization bugs, "flatten" your dictionary like this (create an artificial list for the key just to be able to add it to the values in a list comprehension):

```
d={10:[2,"str1",4] , 20:[5,"str2",7] , 30:[8,"str3",10]}

print([[k]+v for k,v in d.items()])
```

note that the order in the list isn't guaranteed, since order in dicts isn't guaranteed (unless you're using a version where dictionaries keep order like CPython 3.6)

Comment: In Python 3.6+ (the CPython implementation) dicts are ordered.

Comment: yes, but implementation detail. for instance in 3.6 `csv.DictReader` returns a `collections.OrderedDict`, not relying on that order

Comment: In Python 3.7+ "dicts keep insertion order" will be a language feature.

Comment: And that will be very nice. Until 3.6 becomes the norm, we have to warn users about this order issue (note that OP is using python 2.7 as the tag says, and `map` which returns a list is another giveaway :)

Comment: @fferri: more than 40% of production code is still using Python2 syntax, almost ten years after the introduction of Python3. So expecting to safely rely on "dicts keep insertion order" for any piece of Python code, sounds like very deep science-fiction.