# Taking data from a dictionary and putting it into an Excel file using openpyxl

Tags: python, list, dictionary, openpyxl, praw

I am using the Reddit PRAW module to save various attributes of a subreddit into a dictionary
the format of the dictionary is {PostTitle: [id, author, upvotes]}

If I wanted to add the contents of the dictionary into an excel file with each column corresponding to the attributes of the dictionary (A1 = PostTitle B1 = id and so on) how would I do that in openpyxl?

Answer (score 2):

Since openpyxl is working great with lists, your question can be reduced to how to transfer a dictionary of lists into a list of lists, which is answered here:
[Converting Python Dictionary to List of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988684/converting-python-dictionary-to-list-of-lists)

Code for doing what you are asking:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook


wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = 'Posts'

# {PostTitle: [id, author, upvotes]}
data = {
    'Working with Excel1': [
        '111',
        'aaa',
        '1'
    ],
    'Working with Excel2': [
        '222',
        'bbb',
        '2'
    ],
    'Working with Excel3': [
        '333',
        'ccc',
        '3'
    ],
}

for record in [[k]+v for k,v in data.items()]:
    ws.append(record)

wb.save('Reddit.xlsx')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: maybe it would be more readable for beginners: `for title, attributes in data.items():  record = [title] + attributes ; ws.append(record)`