# Use openpyxl to populate columns with values from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I have a dictionary of filenames and corresponding values that I want to populate to a spreadsheet with openpyxl. In the code I've included a small example dict.

The filenames are already in Column A of Sheet1 but I'm struggling to populate the values to Column B in the corresponding rows. There isn't a logical order to the files so I've written a function to iterate over Column A and populate Column B when the required filename is found. I then run the dict through that function. At the moment it's returning a `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.

I'm thinking there's definitely a more straightforward way to do this...

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl

dict = {'file_a': 20, 'file_b': 30, 'file_c': 40}

file = 'spreadsheey.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=True)
ws = wb.active

def populate_row(filename, length): 
    for row in ws.iter_rows('A'):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == filename:
                ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value = length

for key, value in dict.items():
    populate_row(key, value)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try looking at [Taking data from a dictionary and putting it into an Excel file using Openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71182877/taking-data-from-a-dictionary-and-putting-it-into-an-excel-file-using-openpyxl).